# How to wait for one job in a set of slurm jobs to finish

Tags: wait, hpc, slurm

I have started *n* slurm jobs and I would like to let a separate process wait until at least one of them has finished. The waiting process should use as little cpu time as possible so polling would not be ideal (unless there is no other way).

I know of the `scontrol wait_job`, but as far as I can see this can only wait for exactly one job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sufficient privileges, you can use [strigger](https://slurm.schedmd.com/strigger.html).

Otherwise, you could use a workflow manager (for instance [Fireworks](https://materialsproject.github.io/fireworks/)). They typically do polling but at a reasonable pace.

Note that if the action to take is to submit another job, you can also submit it right away and use the `--dependency` parameter to delay its execution until ready.

Comment: Thanks! The `--dependency` should solve my issue. If I have started two jobs with ids 1 and 2 I could start my third job with `--dependency=afterany:1?afterany:2`. It would then start after either job 1 and job 2 have terminated. Thanks also for the highly interesting links!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run something in the **current session and wait for jobs you have already submitted**, you can wait by submitting a job with a dependency that finishes immediately(will still need to wait for the scheduler, but doesn't require installing anything new and doesn't require a bunch of polling):

```
sbatch --time=<some short time> <usual account args> --wait --dependency afterok:<your jobs> /dev/stdin <<< '#!/bin/bash \n sleep 1'
```

For example:

```
sbatch --time=0:15:00 --account my-account-abc --wait --dependency afterok:12345678:12345679 /dev/stdin <<< '#!/bin/bash \n sleep 1'
```

I know this is kind of late, but hope this helps someone :)